# Problem restarting postgres on OS X

Tags: mac-osx, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL in OS X. I am trying to restart the postgres service. When I attempt to `sudo su postgres`, nothing happens

```
admin$ sudo su postgres
admin$
```

Then, I try using -l and this is what I get

```
admin$ sudo su -l postgres
su: no directory
```

Unless I can get su access to the postgres account, I cannot figure out how to restart postgres

Answer (score 0):

This means that the postgres user does not have a home directory or the directory does not exist/is not accessible

Comment: Thanks. Is it as simple as creating a /home/postgres directory and chowing it to postgres?

Comment: Yes but basically you should use pg_ctl to stop start postgres. The weird thing is I just searched for it on my mac and I could not find it.

Comment: It appears I don't have it installed :) that feels stupid. Anyhow you should search for pg_ctl (find / -name pg_ctl as root). Then use that command to start stop it.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/app-pg-ctl.html